# Logging leads when interactions happen for a contact

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to get as close to SRP in my code as possible. I have a situation where I need to log leads when interactions happen for a contact. A lead may be created or updated. There are three different states that I would like to set leads to.

- Active - new interested interactions causes active lead to be created
- Converted - a existing lead is updated to converted if the product was purchased - this is managed with conversion flag
- Stale - a existing lead is updated to stale if the contact is not interested

```
class LeadGeneration

  def initialize contact_id, options={}
    @lead = Lead.find_or_initialize_by(contact_id: contact_id)

    options.reverse_merge!(conversion: false, interested:true)
    @conversion = options[:conversion]
    @interested = options[:interested]
  end

  def call
    if conversion?
      convert_lead 
    else
      process_lead
    end
  end

  private 

  def lead
    @lead
  end

  def conversion?
    @conversion
  end

  def interested?
    @interested
  end

  def convert_lead
    lead.converted! unless lead.new_record?  # new leads cannot be saved as converted
  end

  def process_lead
    if interested?
      activate_lead
    else
      stale_lead
    end
  end

  def activate_lead
    lead.active!
  end

  def stale_lead
    lead.stale! unless lead.new_record? # new leads cannot be saved as stale
  end
end
```

Right now I feel like I should be splitting up converting a lead and managing stale/active states.  I'm not really sure what to do and tests are a little confusing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you intend to use this class, but the `call` method is very fishy. This method seems to do one of three things: `convert_lead`, `activate_lead` or `stale_lead`. The choice of which of them should actually be executed is made in the `options` argument during object construction.

This is not very easy to understand from reading the code, and I can't really see the reasoning behind it. Is it an implementation of a [Command pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCommand_pattern&ei=TW4-U-6tDur_ygP9u4JA&usg=AFQjCNG7Nqol9kI7bA4uJ_ZXTqCILKPhmA&sig2=zG775kJNDa1jmmy01wfHzQ&bvm=bv.64125504,d.bGQ)? that is not very ruby-like.

Since all this class actually does is quite basic delegation (`@lead.converted!`, `@lead.stale!` or `@lead.active!`) I would consider foregoing this class altogether, and simply doing the action. It is unnecessarily long and convoluted, and hides more than explains what it does.

---

From your comment below I understand that `LeadGeneration` should be a `Service Object`. It is true that service objects may have a single method called `call`, as is suggested in this [blog post](http://jamesgolick.com/2012/5/22/objectify-a-better-way-to-build-rails-applications.html):

> Service objects are responsible for retrieving and/or manipulating
>   data — essentially any work that needs to be done that you might have
>   put in a controller or model object before. They typically only have
>   one method, which I like to define as “#call” (they're usually named
>   something like PictureCreationService, so naming the method #create
>   would seem redundant).

But note, though, the *reason* a single method `call` is allowable - it is apparent from the *class name* **exactly** what the method should do.
If your service object was called `LeadConversionService`, then a `call` method would be good enough.

Being a service object, it is even more important than usual in ruby for the class to be small and transparent.

If you want to go to the extreme SRP suggested in the quote above, you'd have three classes, each with `#call` and `#allowed?` methods:

```
class LeadConversionService
  def initialize(lead)
    @lead = lead
  end

  def call
    @lead.converted!
  end

  def allowed?
    !@lead.new_record?
  end
end
```

OR, you could be a little less extreme, and decide the `LeadGeneration` (or maybe `LeadLifeCycleService`?) is a good enough scope, and let it have three method:

```
class LeadLifeCycleService
  def initialize(lead)
    @lead = lead
  end

  def convert!
    raise LifeCycleException if @lead.new_record?
    @lead.convert!
  end

  def activate!
    @lead.active!
  end

  def stale!
    raise LifeCycleException if @lead.new_record?
    @lead.stale!
  end
end
```

Writing this solution makes it obvious again, that this service doesn't do much, since it only delegates (so it doesn't even save code in your model...). All it does is validates pre-conditions to your actions, which may be better handled by a state-machine, as [@Flambino suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46238/22648).

Comment: It is a service object. I want to ensure that the logic regarding how leads are captured is stored within this service object. Otherwise I would need to pull it out into other objects. From my reading using 'call' is acceptable practice for calling service objects. I had all this logic in my models, but from my reading - it is bad practice to bloat your models with logic not related to basic CRUD. Abstractive it into it's own service object makes is much more testable. Sorry I should have said it is a service object in the question.

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes - updated my answer for service objects...

Comment: Does exposing #allowed? pass the responsibility of knowing to check if a lead can be converted outside the responsibility of the service class? would I not do @lead.converted! if allowed? [Thanks for clearing up so much for me!]

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes - The `#allowed?` method might be part of a _policy_, and not part of the _service_. The `@lead.converted! if allowed?` is not advisable, since it hides errors (as @Flambrino said). A better way would be to **raise an error** `unless allowed?`, or, at least expose a `boolean` as to whether the operation actually occurred.

Answer (score 3):

[Uri already had a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46241/14370) suggesting different approaches. I'd roll this into the `Lead` model too, and treat it as a straight-up state machine.

As far as I can tell, the states, in order, are:

```
Stale → Active (default) → Interested → Converted
```

Point being that you can't transition more than one step at a time (can't convert before being interested, can't be interested unless already active, etc.).

[There are a number of state machine gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines) you can use to your advantage. Many (most?) include a simple DSL allowing you do perform the state transitions, trigger other code when a certain transition happens, etc.

Right now, you're passing either `interested` or `conversion` (or both?) to the initializer, which doesn't make sense without knowing the current state. The logic of your class hides all that, and doesn't provide much feedback (e.g. exceptions) if you attempt to do things "out of step" with the current state. For instance, if I pass `interested: false, conversion: true` what does that mean? Seems illogical. What if I pass `conversion: true` on a stale lead? These things make it confusing.

Comment: Interested and conversion are based off interactions the contact has with out application (you do not need to know the state of the lead). These interactions cause changes to the state in the lead. Eg if the interaction is not interested the lead if set to stale if it exists, if it doesn't exist no lead is captured. I pulled this out to a service object because it violates SRP if I put it into the lead or interaction models. If I put this stuff in my models I would have to use callbacks as well which is bad practice.